# How can I bind :Set to work exactly like :set?

Tags: command-line

I quite often start typing the *s* before fully releasing the shift key, and having to correct the command afterwards is a bit annoying.

Is there any way to make `:Set ...` an alias for `:set ...`?

Comment: I have this exact same problem with `:sp`, `:vs` and `:e`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While you cannot define custom commands starting with lowercase characters (like the built-in ones), nothing prevents you from doing the opposite, defining user commands that mirror the built-in ones.

```
:command! -nargs=* -complete=option Set set <args>
```

If you do this for additional commands, just ensure the number of arguments / taken `:range` / bang (`[!]`) matches. See `:help :command-nargs` (and following paragraphs) for the available options.

#### Warning

Sloppy typing won't get you very far with Vim; instead of relying on such workarounds (which don't work as well in other areas like mappings and motions), better deliberately slow down for a period of time and work on your typing precision. Investing in a higher-quality keyboard might help, too.

Comment: I do have a decent keyboard (WASD with mx clears). But in many cases I just fire up gvim from my task bar (yeah, windows user, no comment :p), `:set syntax=whatever` and then switch to insert mode if i need a code scratchpad for something.

Answer (score 5):

You could remap `;` to `:`, that way there's no more Shift key involved:

```
:noremap ; :
```

This has the obvious downside of losing the function of the `;` key (*"Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times."*), to map this to `:` (and thus swapping `;` and `:`), you can use:

```
:noremap ; :
:noremap : ;
```

The problem with that, though, is that once you're used to it, you'll be semi-crippled in a default Vim installation....

Comment: This is a good idea actually, the fewer times shift is used the better. Also, I hear you regarding getting semi-crippled. I have swapped my `1..90-=` keys with their alternatives `!..()_+` in C, C++ and Haskell files since the alternatives are used much more frequently and it's really nice, but I do get semi-crippled when using vim where my settings are not in effect.

Comment: Using command abbreviations and omitting unnecessary spaces following command would swap `:` and `;` on a default installation to not be semi-crippled: `:no; :|no: ;<cr>` (12 characters have to be typed).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define an abbreviation.

```
:cab Set set
```

As carpetsmoker mentioned this will replace `Set` with `set` everywhere in the command line. To avoid this use

```
:cnoreab Set set
```

Comment: Note that this will replace `Set` with `set` *everywhere* in the command line, not just when you type `:Set`